# Multiple columns using Block and nicematrix package

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multicolumn, booktabs

I would like to write text into multiple columns using the `nicematrix` and `booktabs` packages.

However, there is the unwanted spacing, circled in the picture.

Is there any way to get rid of it so that the three columns are vertically aligned?

Solutions using other ways to do this are welcome, but they must:

- Be able to show the equation with adequate spacing above and below, as the booktabs package does automatically
- Have the vertical lines

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|p{3.9em}| p{14em} |p{10em} | p{10em}|}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} \\
        \midrule
        H&H&H&$\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\right)^{10}$\\
        \midrule
        Test
        &
        Test Test Test TestTestTest TestTest Test TestTest TestTest TestTestTest TestTestTestTestTest TestTestTest
        &
        \Block{1-2}{
            \begin{minipage}{22em}
                Test Test Test TestTestTest TestTest Test TestTest TestTest TestTestTest TestTestTestTestTest TestTestTest
        \end{minipage}}
    &
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome To TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`nicematrix` package provides the option `T` for blocks to align columns. `\Block` does not create space if it has two or more rows/columns. You still need to determine the space for your text manually by specifying columns widths and number of `\tabcolsep` in `minipage` environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\widthWidest}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testText}{}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobor- tis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.}

\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=[gray]{0.75}, hvlines}

\begin{document}
    
    \setlength{\widthWidest}{\widthof{\textbf{Header 1}}}%
    \begin{NiceTabular}{p{\widthWidest} p{10em} p{10em} p{10em}}
        
        \toprule
        
        \RowStyle[bold]{} Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4
        \\
        \midrule
        
        Test
        &
        \Block[T, l]{1-1}{
    
            \smash{\rlap{\rule{\dimexpr 30em + 4\tabcolsep \relax}{0.1pt}}}%
            \testText
            
        }
        &
        \Block[T]{1-2}{
            
            \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 20em + 2\tabcolsep \relax}
                
                \raggedright
                
                \testText
                
            \end{minipage}
            
        }
        &
        \\
        
        \bottomrule
        
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make the text fully justified (i.e. not raggedright)? Also, is there a way to vertically center the texts?

Comment: @cmb2200. Load `ragged2e` package and use `\justifying` inside `\Block`. When you remove the key `T`, you get vertical centering of the contents

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with `nicematrix`, but your table is simple to write by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {l X[1.2, j] *{2}{X[0.8, j]}},
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                 rowsep  = 3pt,
                 hspan   = minimal
                 }
    \toprule
Test    &   Test    &   Test    &   Test    \\
    \midrule
H       &   H       &   H       &   $\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\right)^{10}$\\
    \midrule
Test    & \lipsum[66]
                    &   \SetCell[c=2]{j}    \lipsum[11]
                                &           \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

After only one compilation you will get the final result:

[image]

In the case, that you like that table has vertical lines, just add in table preamble `vlines` option:

```
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {l X[1.2, j] *{2}{X[0.8, j]}},
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                 rowsep  = 3pt,
                 hspan   = minimal,
                 vlines
                 }
```

and table will be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a fairly simple table. You wouldn't need to load `nicematrix` in this case. `\multicolumn` is enough to sort it out.

Regarding the rules, if you want to use those defined in `booktabs`, still have vertical lines, and avoid small gaps, one way is to remove spaces around the rules and stretch the table by increasing a factor of `arraystretch`.

Also the equation has a larger height and would stick to top and bottom lines by default. This is usually sorted out by adding a strut, e.g. `\xmathstrut` from `mathtools` package to stretch this particular cell individually.

Because of the size of your table, the code uses `sidewaystable` which renders its content vertically (see [rotating](https://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) documentation for more info).

Here's the table:

[image]

and the code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}       % for \newcolumntype and \extrarowheight
\usepackage{mathtools}   % for \xmathstrut
\usepackage{rotating}    % for sidewaystable
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{p{#1}}   % >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}
\newcommand\header[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    %%% Stretch table
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.75}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{-1.5pt}
    %%% Remove spaces around rules
    \setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
    \setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
    %%%
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|
            P{3.9em}|
            P{14em}|
            *2{P{10em}|}
        }
        \toprule
        \header{Test}
        & \header{Test} & \header{Test} & \header{Test} \\
        \midrule
        H & H & H & $\xmathstrut{0.75}
                     {0.75} \left(
                                \frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}
                            \right)^{10}$ \\
        \midrule
        Test
        & \kant[2][2]
        & \multicolumn{2}{P{\dimexpr20em+2\tabcolsep}|}{\kant[1][1]} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```